# Set/Get Methods for Private Fields in Super/Sub classes

Tags: java, subclass, private, superclass

So basically I have a superclass of a Geometric Figure that has private fields, say length and width. I have a subclass of a Rectangle that has a length and width in the constructor.

In the subclass, I must include a method to set the length and width of the Rectangle to the length and width of the private fields of the Geometric Figure. How do I do this?

Thanks

EDIT: For example:

```
public class GeometricFigure{
private double length;
private double width;
}

public class Rectangle extends GeometricFigure{
     public Rectangle(int length, int width){}
//set and get methods here to set the private fields to the variables in the parameter
}
```

Comment: What??!! provide some piece of code pleaseeeeee

Comment: Use the `super` keyword.

Comment: you got your issue resolved?

Comment: Not yet. Basically I need to have the code for the problem in the subclass, not superclass.

Comment: Remember one thing bro, you can't access private members of a class directly from outside that class until you use Reflection!

Comment: What does Reflection do? How do I use it?

Comment: @noobforce Reflection provides access to the bytecode, and so does some funny (or messy, depends of the point of view) thing on runtime. But if you're learning Java basics, I don't think your teacher want you to do this ;) (more information [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create getter and setter methods in the superclass like:

```
public GeometricFigure(int length, int width)
{
     this.length = length;
     this.width = width;
}

public Rectangle(int length, int width)
{
    super(length, width);
}
```

Your 2 constructors could look like this.

Comment: I'm not supposed to do it like that. My teacher says the superclass cannot have any methods.

Comment: Then add them to superclass constructor

Comment: Apparantly the constructor in the superclass is supposed to be empty.

Comment: @noobforce No way to do what you are asking unless you make attributes in superclass public or protected.

Comment: Meh. I'll just do what you said and look at it later. Thanks.

Comment: (hoping that someone sees this) I tried doing what you typed in the code, but I still get the error that I cannot access the private field because it is private...

Comment: @noobforce sorry I gave you the wrong syntax it should just be `super(length, width);` in your subclass constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options,

1. Provide constructor in super class which accepts width and length. Subclass will use it
2. Provide setter/getter method in super class which accepts width and length, just use it in the subclass

Otherwise you have no access to set private fields. (except reflection)

Comment: Would I need to use a super() call or anything like that?

Comment: if the constructor is in super class yes, you need to call super, if you use the methods, just make them protected so you can just call them